# Unrecognized element 'remove' web.config

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to delete a `Member Groups` in Umbraco CMS but I'm getting a 500 error. When I checked the event log I get this error

```
Exception message: Unrecognized element 'remove'. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\fakesite.com\web.config line 155)
```

I'm not sure what's this but I already deleted all records from `cmsMember2MemberGroup` so I'm sure no member is using this. But somehow it's throwing an error.Am I missing some configuration in the web.config file? If so what should I add.. Well I can always just delete their entry in the DB but I don't want to do that. Is there a way  to fix this issue?

Update:

THis is the content of Line 155:

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
        <customErrors allowNestedErrors="true" defaultRedirect="https://www.fakesite.com/page-not-found/" mode="On">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="https://www.fakesite.com/page-not-found/"/>
        </customErrors>
```

Comment: Please show us line 155 of that config file.

Comment: @mjwills updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to post this as an answer but I do not have enough karma to leave a comment.

I am shooting in the dark but aren't remove elements supposed to be added programatically through `CustomErrorCollection.Remove(String)`? This is what I took from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.customerrorcollection.remove?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).

`The Remove method inserts a remove element into the customErrors section of the configuration file at the current hierarchy level. This removes the reference to the add element defined in the parent configuration files at higher levels in the hierarchy.`

Comment: thanks for the link. I'm not sure why but it's only affecting the Live application but our Staging application that is hosted in Azure does not throw this kind of error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it makes sense to use `remove` inside custom errors. All the examples from Umbraco seem to only use `remove` inside HTTP errors.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/500.aspx">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx"/>
            <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/500.aspx"/>
        </customErrors>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="404"/>
            <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File"/>
            <remove statusCode="500"/>
            <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" responseMode="File"/>
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```